# PHP реадктирование строки таблицы

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

Суть задачи: для каждой записи (строки) таблицы необходимо добавить кнопку SUBMIT () "Редактировать запись", которая методом POST открывает новую форму (страницу) развернутого редактирования. 
Вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю, что для каждая такая кнопка SUBMIT (для каждой записи), должна быть в отдельном теге FORM?
Например:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <form action='sttm_edit.php' method='post'>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' id='btn_sttm_edit_1' name='btn_sttm_edit'>...</button>
                <input type='hidden' id='sttm_id_1' name='sttm_id' value='1'>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2019-02-21</td>
        <td>Пётр Петров</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>
            <form action='sttm_edit.php' method='post'>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' id='btn_sttm_edit_2' name='btn_sttm_edit'>...</button>
                <input type='hidden' id='sttm_id_2' name='sttm_id' value='2'>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2019-02-21</td>
        <td>Иванна Иванова</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Нет не правильно. Тег `<form>` должен быть один на странице. И немного странное задание. Я бы по клику сделал бы текст редактируемым, а по завершению редактирования отправлял бы `json` на сервер

Comment: Форма редактирования очень большая, включая WYSIWYG... 
Записей в исходной таблице много и выводятся они выборкой из базы данных.

Comment: Так вы создайте `div` с классом `edit` (например) и повести на него событие `click`. Или создайте кнопку с классом, можно аналогичным, на который повесите событие, которое, например по клику, оборачивает текст ячейки в `textarea`. По завершении редактирования вновь нажать кнопку. по нажатию которой отправить данные куда надо и подменить `textarea` обратно.

Comment: Подобная задача, там (п.5) <form> в цикле: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/wish-list-lesson7_ru.html

Comment: "Тег `<form>` должен быть один на странице"  это кто такое сказал?

Comment: А по вопросу - неясно зачем вам открывать форму методом `$_POST`? Сделайте обычную ссылку `<a href="edit.php?id=КАКОЙ_ТО ИД"` и открывайте страницы на редактирование.